# External Play Pause Button Swap SVG & Text on State Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, jwplayer

I have an external button below the playback window used to toggle play and pause, which has a CSS SVG background image with the following code, works great:

```
<a onclick="jwplayer().play();" class="jwp-btn jwp-btn-icon-pl">Play</a>
```

What I want to do is a state change, so that if the `"> Play"` is displayed on the button, and the user clicks the button to play, that the SVG, and text swaps to `"|| Pause"` (using a different SVG and text). And then reverses back if the button is clicked again.

I suspect that this will use JavaScript (which I'm OK with, jQuery is OK too), and `jwplayer().on('play')` and `jwplayer().on('pause')` event triggers. The SVG icon does not have to be in CSS.

But I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this.

Here's the player code (using a playlist as well):

```
<script>
              var playerInstance = jwplayer("containerpreview");
                playerInstance.setup({
                  //file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/12345.mp4",
                  //image: "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs23456.jpg",
                  //playlist: "//content.jwplatform.com/feeds/123.rss",
                  playlist: "//cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/222?format=mrss",
                  displaytitle: false,
                  width: "100%",
                  aspectratio: "16:9"
                });

                var list = document.getElementById("list");
                var html = list.innerHTML;

                playerInstance.on('ready',function(){
                var playlist = playerInstance.getPlaylist();
                for (var index=0;index<playlist.length;index++){
                var playindex = index +1;
                html += "<li><span class='dropt' title='"+playlist[index].title+"'><a href='javascript:playThis("+index+")'><img height='75' width='120' src='" + playlist[index].image + "'</img></br>"+playlist[index].title+"</a></br><span style='width:500px;'</span></span></li>"
                list.innerHTML = html;
                }

                });

                function playThis(index) {
                playerInstance.playlistItem(index);
                }

              </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any `HTML`, `Js` code about your file (just a single `a` tag is not enough), but this will give you an idea about how you can do this:

**js/jQuery:**

```
 jwplayer("containerpreview").on('play', function(){
      $('.jwp-btn').empty().html("Your (Pause)SVG Element");
 });

 jwplayer("containerpreview").on('pause', function(){
      $('.jwp-btn').empty().html("Your (Play)SVG Element");
 });
```

Comment: Not getting this to work, player won't display at all when I insert this: 

jwplayer().on('play', function(){
               $('.jwp-btn').empty().html("<img src="/img/icons/18/icon-pause-grey-18.svg" alt="Click to Pause"> Pause");
          });

          jwplayer().on('pause', function(){
               $('.jwp-btn').empty().html("<img src="/img/icons/18/icon-play-grey-18.svg" alt="Click to Play"> Play");
          });

Comment: Any errors? Maybe you should wrapp them all into `jwplayer().on('ready', function(){ THE CODE GOES HERE});`

Comment: Tried your suggestion, player still no longer will load.  Looking for errors, debugger not showing any.

Comment: @gigaboy How you setup `jwplayer()`? You just sat .. Aha now i saw your edit. welldone

Comment: @gigaboy I edited my answer as well, and included your `#id` => `containerpreview` in it. Hope this one works

Comment: @gigaboy or use your instance, its easier. like this: `playerInstance.on('play', function(){ $('.jwp-btn').empty().html("Your (Pause)SVG Element"); });`

Comment: Got it to work, in the html() string, changed from double quotes to single quotes surrounding the html code.  Thus,  

jwplayer().on('play', function(){
             $('.jwp-btnl').empty().html('<img src="/img/icons/18/icon-pause-grey-18.svg" alt="Click to Pause"> Pause');
           });

          jwplayer().on('pause', function(){
            $('.jwp-btn').empty().html('<img src="/img/icons/18/icon-play-grey-18.svg" alt="Click to Play"> Play');
          });

Comment: @gigaboy wellplayed sir ;) yeap double quotation has collision with html tag attributes